# nsExtendOutput1Line Fails with SNMPD on Debian Wheezy

Tags: snmp, cacti

I've been trying to set up a a few SNMP extensions. Here's a sample entry from /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf on my target host:

```
extend php_pids /var/skotos/cacti/check-proc lsphp5
```

The program works fine:

```
#  /var/skotos/cacti/check-proc lsphp5
There are 26 lsphp5 processes.
```

However, when I go to my cacti server, I get errors:

```
snmpwalk -c <community> <site> 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."php_pids"'

NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."php_pids": Unknown Object Identifier
```

(I get timeouts from Cacti, but I figured snmpwalk would take out the middle man.)

Everything else works fine for Cacti on the server and for SNMP on the target, but for some reason I can't get nsExtendOutput1Line to work at all.

This is a very fresh Debian Wheezy 7.4 isntallation.

Answer (score 1):

Due to licencing issues MIB database was removed from the libsnmp-base sometime ago, so currently your client cannot translate the names to OIDs. You can query the snmpd server using the object identifier directly, by: (asking for first line of the output)

```
snmpwalk -c <community> <site> 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1
```

Alternatively you can install the package snmp-mibs-downloader which is in the non-free repository.

```
apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

It should download the database automatically, but if for some reason it doesn't just run the "download-mibs" script. After the database is properly downloaded the command:

```
snmpwalk -c <community> <site> 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."php_pids"'
```

should just work.